# Rails vendor plugin failure in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I expect this to be a n00b problem.

I'm attempting to use heroku with my rails app.  Everything works fine in development (local machine), but when I push to heroku I get the following:

```
==> dyno-1931938.log (crash) <==
/home/slugs/258915_4fd8878_0dbe-1413ed77-735c-469d-924e-619b28cdcbac/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:1016:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `acts_as_paranoid' for #<Class:0x2b469869b658> (NameError)
    from /disk1/home/slugs/258915_4fd8878_0dbe-1413ed77-735c-469d-924e-619b28cdcbac/mnt/app/models/my_model.rb:17
```

lines 16 and 17 of `my_model.rb` are:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
```

'acts_as_paranoid' is a vendor plugin that was installed locally via:

```
$git clone https://github.com/goncalossilva/rails3_acts_as_paranoid.git
```

What am I doing wrong that heroku is ignoring the plugin?

---

UPDATE:
  I cloned the repo from heroku, and the directory for the plugin exists, but is empty.  My other plugins (i.e. ssl_requirement) have the expect lib/ and init.rb.  Obviously the code needs to be there to work.  What now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `vendor/plugins/my_plugin_directory` had fallen out of the git tree.  I resolved the problem by:

```
$cd rails_root_directory
$git fsck
$git rm --cached vendor/plugins/my_plugin_directory
$git add vendor/plugins/my_plugin_directory/*
$git commit -am "my_plugin added to repository"
$git push heroku master
```

and all is right now.

Comment: Hmmm - have you managed to get acts_as_paranoid working with a Rails 3 project? On mine it can no longer find a lot of the active record methods that it depends upon...

Comment: I'm using rails3-acts-as-paranoid: https://github.com/goncalossilva/rails3_acts_as_paranoid

Answer (score 2):

Cloning the source retrieves the code from github, but it doesn't install the gem into your app. Normally you'd install the gem on your local machine like this:

```
gem install acts_as_paranoid
```

or

```
sudo gem install acts_as_paranoid
```

Then tell Heroku about the gem by adding this to your .gems file:

```
acts_as_paranoid
```

or better yet, specify the version that you expect, too (otherwise Heroku will grab the latest every time you push up new code to your app, which could cause unexpected breakage):

```
acts_as_paranoid --version x.y.z
```

And make sure your config/environment.rb has an entry for the gem so its absence will be detected at launch instead of later:

```
config.gem 'acts_as_paranoid', :version => 'x.y.z'
```

PS: All of the above will be somewhat different if you're using Rails 3 and/or Bundler to manage your gems.

Comment: This being a plugin and not an gem isn't there a different procedure?  Also, I've modified the plugin, so I want to use my local copy not one from a repository.   Yes I am using rails 3/bundler.

Comment: Yeah if it's a true plugin it should just fine from your vendor/plugins directory. In this case it's both a gem and a plugin so you could use either approach.

Comment: Right, in your situation (modified code) a plugin makes more sense. Glad you found a solution. I'll leave my answer here in case it helps someone who has the gem option.